# Flask raises TemplateNotFound error even though files in right place

Tags: python, html, web-services, flask, environment-variables

after trying to render `index.html` file in python it comes up with the `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html` error.
The files are saved like this:

```
flaskTest/
    flaskTest.py
    templates/
        index.html
```

the code is also very simple and works without the template_render function:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The only thing I can think of is that my environmental variables are somehow set wrong - I had issues with them whilst installing flask, but I can't see why they would affect this. Why will flask not find the html file?

also, I know this question is similar to others (specifically the one asked by Martijn Pieters), but I've tried the solutions suggested and it still doesn't work (in Martijn Pieters question it says to put the html file in a templates folder which I've done).

Comment: Which command are you using to run your code?

Comment: @aaossa I don't run it through a terminal, I just press f5 in the IDE lmao.